# Error 9 displayed when using my own defined arrays in this code in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have 2 arrays taken from 2 ranges in a sheet. I'm trying to create a third array that contains only the values contained in array 1 that are missing in array 2 (I found this code online).

Array 2´s size will vary and depends on this code:

```
Dim iListaIncompleta() As Variant 
Dim iCountLI As Long 
Dim iElementLI As Long
iCountLI = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
ReDim iListaIncompleta(iCountLI)
For iElementLI = 1 To iCountLI 
iListaIncompleta(iElementLI - 1) = Cells(iElementLI, 2).Value
Next iElementLI
```

and Array 1's size is always from A1:A7, and I use this code to create it:

```
Dim iListaCompleta() As Variant 
Dim iElementLC As Long
iListaCompleta = Range("A1:A7")
```

This is the original code I found online to extract missing values:

```
Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long

'Original Arrays from the code:
v1 = Array("Bob", "Alice", "Thor", "Anna") 'Complete list
v2 = Array("Bob", "Thor") 'Incomplete list

Set coll = New Collection

For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
    If v1(i) <> 0 Then
    coll.Add v1(i), v1(i) 'Does not add value if it's 0
    End If
Next i

For i = LBound(v2) To UBound(v2)
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add v2(i), v2(i)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        coll.Remove v2(i)
    End If
    If coll.Exists(v2(i)) Then 
        coll.Remove v2(i)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

ReDim v3(LBound(v1) To (coll.Count) - 1) 

For i = LBound(v3) To UBound(v3)
    v3(i) = coll(i + 1) 'Collections are 1-based
    Debug.Print v3(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

However, this code has arrays defined like this:

```
v1 = Array("Bob", "Alice", "Thor", "Anna")
```

And the actual arrays I wanna use are defined differently (as you can see in the first two pieces of code). When I try to run the code with them, it displays

> Error 9: Subscript out of range.

The code works well as it originally is, but when I try to use MY arrays, it's when I get this error.

Obviously, I've tried it changing the names of the variables (v1 and v2) to my own 2 arrays (iListaCompleta and iListaIncompleta), and still doesn't work.

Any ideas??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code you've found is dealing with arrays of one dimension. Your arrays have two dimensions.

Comment: An array created from a range is 2-dimensional. You need to access it with `iListaCompleta(i, 1)` the first index is rows, the second is columns. Since it is only the row that changes in your range you can just leave the second index at 1. Do be aware as well that an array created from a range will be 1-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can be used to compare arrays of any dimension size to pull out differences and put only the differences in a one-dimensional array:

```
Public Function ArrayDifference(ByVal arg_Array1 As Variant, ByVal arg_array2 As Variant) As Variant
    
    If Not IsArray(arg_Array1) Or Not IsArray(arg_array2) Then Exit Function    'Arguments provided were not arrays
    
    Dim vElement As Variant
    Dim hDifference As Object:  Set hDifference = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each vElement In arg_Array1
        If Not hDifference.exists(vElement) Then hDifference.Add vElement, vElement
    Next vElement
    
    For Each vElement In arg_array2
        If hDifference.exists(vElement) Then
            hDifference.Remove vElement
        Else
            hDifference.Add vElement, vElement
        End If
    Next vElement
    
    ArrayDifference = hDifference.Keys
    
End Function
```

Here's how you would call the function to compare two different arrays. It also includes how to populate the initial arrays using your provided setup:

```
Sub arrays()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim rList1 As Range:    Set rList1 = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim rList2 As Range:    Set rList2 = ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim aList1 As Variant
    If rList1.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aList1(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aList1(1, 1) = rList1.Value
    Else
        aList1 = rList1.Value
    End If
    
    Dim aList2 As Variant
    If rList2.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aList2(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aList2(1, 1) = rList2.Value
    Else
        aList2 = rList2.Value
    End If
    
    Dim aList3 As Variant
    aList3 = ArrayDifference(aList1, aList2)
    
    MsgBox Join(aList3, Chr(10))
    
End Sub
```